# Adding a SVN repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm trying to add an SVN repository to Eclipse.

I've installed [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), and it seems to be working fine. But, when I try to "add a new SVN repository", I input this, for example:

*http://svn.python.org/projects/peps/trunk*

I get this:

> Error validating location: "org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed 
>   svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.python.org/projects/peps/trunk': could not connect to server (http://svn.python.org)
>   "
>   Keep location anyway?

I know that my Eclipse can connect to the Internet, because I downloaded Subclipse earlier (I had to change my proxy settings).

I get a similar message for other SVN locations I've tried to add.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 19):

This is a dead topic, but the solution is to install a client adapter along with Subclipse.

Take a look at [this](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-da671f9d3dd97d874248445af428545727a8271a), and install SVN Client Adapter, SVNKit Adapter, and SVNKit Library.

Then check under Window -> Preference -> Team -> SVN and make sure there is an entry for SVN Interface.

And for future reference, if you can connect to the repository through the command line, then it must be a problem with the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How does one install SVN Client Adapter? There are no binaries distributed only the source code. What should I do once I've built it?

Comment: You should just be able to install it from Eclipse's software tool. In Eclipse go to Install New Software. Get Subclipse's update URL from http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA and then there should be a Subclipse -> Subversion Client Adapter that takes care of it for you. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I have entry for SVN Interface as well but still I get this error :(

Comment: Same here, does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 19):

It worked for me, In eclipse: Window > Preference > Team > SVN: select **SVNKit (Pure Java)** instead **JavaHL(JNI)**

Comment: Funny enough, I had it already on SVNKit, but just changed back to JavaHL... Whatever, now it works, I guess. :)

Answer (score 6):

At my day job I sit behind a corporate firewall protecting and caching web traffic (among other things). For the most part it stays out of the way. But sometimes it rears its ugly head and stands firmly in the path of what I am trying to do.

Earlier this week I was trying to look at a cool new general validation system for ColdFusion called Validat, put out by the great guys at Alagad. They don't have a download on the RIAForge site yet, but the files are available via SVN. I loaded up the subclipse plugin into my Eclipse, restarted and began adding the Validat SVN repository. I started getting errors abou the "RA layer request failed" and "svn: PROPFIND request failed on /Validat/trunk", followed by an error about not being able to connect to the SVN server.

I already had Eclipse setup with my proxy settings, so I thought I was doing something wrong or Alagad didn't actually have the subversion repository up-and-available. After going home that night, I tried it from home and wa-la it worked. Stupid proxy server! So the subclipse plugin won't use the Eclipse proxy settings. (Can that be fixed please!). After digging around the subclipse help site and being redirected to the collab.net help, then unproductively searching through the eclipse workspace, plugins, and configuration folders for the settings file, I was finally able to figure out how to set up subclipse to use the proxy server.

In my Windows development environment, I opened the following file: C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserId\Application Data\Subversion\servers in my favorite text editor. Near the bottom of that file is a [global] section with http-proxy-host and http-proxy-port settings. I uncommented those two lines, modified them for my corporate proxy server, went back to the SVN Repository view in Eclipse, refreshed the Validat repository and Boom! it worked!

from http://www.mkville.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/11/8/Using-Subclipse-Behind-a-Proxy-Server

Answer (score 3):

Try to connect to the repository using command line SVN to see if you get a similar error.

```
$ svn checkout http://svn.python.org/projects/peps/trunk
```

If you keep getting the error, it is probably an issue with your proxy server.
I have found that I can't check out internet based SVN projects at work because the firewall blocks most HTTP commands.  It only allows GET, POST and others necessary for browsing.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that Subclipse and then SVN can use your Eclipse proxy settings. You'll probably need to set the proxy for your SVN program itself. Trying to check out the files using SVN from the command line should tell you if that works.

If SVN can't connect either then put the proxy settings in your servers file in your Subversion settings folder (in your home folder).

If it can't do it even with the proxy settings set, then your firewall is probably blocking the methods and protocols that Subversion needs to use to download the files.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to connect to the Collabnet subversion from eclipse I was also getting the same error as 'Peter Hilton' described in his original post. 
I changed the settings of Active Provided from 'Native' to 'manual' in windows->Preferences->General->Network Connections.
This worked for me. I think this was a proxy problem but with my old settints eclipse was connecting to the internet from where i DOWNLOADED THE subversion plugins.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably of little help to you, but I enter that URL into Subclipse and the repository adds fine and I can browse and Show History on it.

Do you perhaps need to configure a proxy?  You have to configure that in the Subversion runtime configuration area as Subclipse uses the Subversion libraries to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any working repositories in this instance of eclipse?

I've had problems in the past with the default Subclipse subversion client on Windows, you need to make sure the native subversion client is installed and correctly configured (I've got TortoiseSVN to work in the past) if you want to use the default client adapter.

On a recent install I tried the "beta" drivers (I have Eclipse Ganymede and "SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.2.0.4502") that you can optionally install with Subclipse and they worked pretty much straight out of the box, although a colleague found he had to go through a few hoops to make sure Eclipse installed them (and their dependancies) correctly.

Here are the packages that appear in "Help" -> "Software Updates" -> "Installed Software":

```
Subclipse                  1.4.0
Subversion Client Adapter  1.5.0.1
SVNKit Client Adapter      1.5.0.1
SVNKit Library             1.2.0.4502
```

These are probably a little out of date now, and the latest version will probably work better, but this is what I can see working right now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem when I changed my SVN password.

How to resolve
First, remove Subversion folder in {Documents and Settings}{user login}\Application Data\Subversion  -> It doesn't work

After, rename my current user login profile from {Documents and Settings}{user login} to  {Documents and Settings}{user login}_bakup and login agian -> It work...

I assumed -> SVN or JavaHL bind authorized user with {user login} or keep it in user profile of window.

Answer (score 1):

I has the same problem. McAFee had blocked the eclipse. solve it in the manager McAFee> Firewall> progamas internet connection to> find the eclipse and allow full access.

regards

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem and, as mentioned previously here, I changed the "servers" file under Subversion folder in "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\Subversion". There, in the file's bottom, there is a [global] section. I removed the comments from

http-proxy-host 
http-proxy-port 
http-proxy-username
http-proxy-password

I set those guys and it worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error and solved by switching off the proxy settings in TortoiseSVN that I normally need for commits to the company servers. I installed Subclipse to back up my own non-prime-time stuff to a local repository (using VisualSVN). I use Eclipse Galileo 3.3 and Subclipse 1.6.12.

Answer (score 0):

Necropost, but helpful: I came across this problem with an RA request failed since the files "already existed on the server" but wouldn't sync with my repository.  I went to the source on my disk, deleted there, refreshed my Eclipse view, and updated the source.  Error gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was an access issue. I needed to change the protocol to svn+ssh instead of http.

For example, instead of
http://svn.python.org/projects/peps/trunk

try 
svn+ssh://svn.python.org/projects/peps/trunk

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the websecurity of vpn client is the issue. I uninstalled it and it worked fine..Found the solution here
https://superuser.com/questions/471089/svn-connection-not-successful

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue with you. I have TortoiseSVN installed on my windows, I have also eclipse installed, in the eclipse, I have the subclipse 1.4 installed.

here is the issue
I have proxy settings, I can open the repo through web browser, for some reason, I cannot open a repo through svn. I tried to change the proxy following the link below [Eclipse Kepler not connecting to internet via proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338212/eclipse-kepler-not-connecting-to-internet-via-proxy). It doesn't work.

Finally I found out a solution

You have to change the proxy setting in TortoiseSVN. After I enable the proxy setting the same with my browser. The issue is gone.

here is the link of how to enable proxy setting in TortoiseSVN 
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html
Seach "Network Settings" on the page above

Comment: Thanks man. I'm not even even using Eclipse these days. Knee deep in a Visual Studio project in C++.Appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, im getting the similar exception when trying to checkout the project from SVN repo it is prompting for the username and password and i was giving the wrong username every time, when i gave the **correct username and password** its started working fine.....
Such a simple and Hardstopping message.....