# svn could not connect to server

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm trying out to checkout a project of mine at ProjectLocker SVN in another computer running Windows 7. I'm using Subclipse but I get the error:

```
RA layer request failed
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/cvmig_prism/PRISM/svn'
svn: PROPFIND of '/cvmig_prism/PRISM/svn': could not connect to server (https://pl3.projectlocker.com)
```

However, I can check out other projects from Google Code. I've tried a few of the tips at [Adding a SVN repository in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85486/adding-a-svn-repository-in-eclipse) except for the top answer because, hey, *I can* checkout other repos (unlike the OP in the linked question) and internet here is crappy for a download (I downloaded Eclipse et. al. from home and just installed).

I have set my proxy and the only thing I can think of right now is that, my ProjectLocker repo requires a username and password. But, shouldn't svn ask me for that *after* I have connected successfully to the server? Is there anything I have overlooked?

Comment: Can you `ping` your server? Do you see anything if you aim your browser at `https://pl3.projectlocker.com`? Does your URL need the username:password added to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in the Preferences --> SVN Interface from your current setting to another. Cleanup. Change to the original interface.

Hope it helps....