# Eclipse Repository Tortoise SVN Connection Error

Tags: android, eclipse, tortoisesvn

Iam having Tortoise SVN client repo in my system. Now i need to connect to the repository from another system which is linked in lan from eclipse.I have installed subclipse plugin for eclipse. but when i tried to create a repository I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your path is wrong, or you don't have privileges. That's the usual cause for the error.

Also, check if your SVN connector is the same version as the SVN installed on the server.

**Edit**:

[Similar topic here. Read through those answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85486/adding-a-svn-repository-in-eclipse)

Comment: svn://10.32.4.136/Android repo is connection with other systems is working

Comment: No still iam not able to connect